# Apples to Apples comparison?

Tags: number-comparison, scoring-algorithm

I calculate a scores of different sets of data like this:

$$scores_j = avg(x_{j,i} * a_i)$$

where $a_i$ are constant and $x_{j,i}$ change between data sets.
Let say I have as a result:

$$scores_1 = (10,20,30)$$
$$scores_2 = (10,20,40)$$

then I rescale them to the range of 0 .. 100

$$scores_1 = (0,50,100)$$
$$scores_2 = (0,33,100)$$

My question is by comparing  33 =?= 55, m'I comparing Apples to Apples OR Apples to Oranges ?
/the same for 0 and 100/

If they are not comparable, how can I make them comparable ?

---

lets say X is a preference from 0 .. 1 of feature F and A is support of feature F for item M  , 0 .. 1

Comment: If you want to keep the quotient of differences constant then you´re right. $$\textrm{Score 1: }  \frac{30-20}{20-10}=\frac{100-50}{50-0}=1,$$  $$\textrm{Score 2:  } \frac{40-20}{20-10}=\frac{100-33\frac13}{33\frac13-0}=2$$ I have $33\frac13$ instead of $33$

Comment: y.. i was rounding it

Comment: i know i'm keeping Q.. but can i compare 50 and 33.. given that they were generated by diff X's /range of X is the same in every dataset/

Comment: It depends on the context. Another measure: It depends on the context if the relative change or the absolute change is the appropriate measure.

Comment: let say X can be 0 .. 1, but dataset1 uses vals 0.1 .. 0.7 and dataset2 0.4 .. 0.8